# 503 Litespeed Python error: The server is temporarily busy, try again later

Tags: python, web-hosting, litespeed

I am using shared linux hosting and I am trying to setup a Python app using the Python selector. Firstly, when you setup the app, the website should be saying:
`It works!` and the `python version`.

However I am getting a 503 error saying `The server is temporarily busy, try again later!`.

I tried setting up an app using the NodeJS selector and it worked without a problem. The server that the hosting uses is Litespeed. I have no root access.

If anyone can help, I will be very thankful!

Comment: Please check doc and see if it helps. 
https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051851034-Why-does-my-python-application-created-with-CloudLinux-Python-Selector-show-a-503-error-when-using-LiteSpeed-

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: I did found an article for this. 
https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cloudlinux:enable_ruby_python_selector

If you are able to complete from this. Please help me too.
I cannot run `yum` command